# Vim run custom command immediately upon :e

Tags: nmap, shortcut

The below mapping takes me to another file.
The problem is that once I have opened the file, the screen is always,
too far up. I adjust that with zt.
How do I implement zt in the destination file automatically, every time i run the shortcut?

```
nnoremap mh :w<Enter> :e +/string_i_start_at/ ~/somefolder/somefile.vim<CR>;
```

The following question is related, except doesn't tackle opening via :e
when one is already in the file.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6821033/322537

Comment: I suspect the `;` at the end of your mapping is a bug. Probably romainl copied it in their answer to not disturb it if it works for you, but I suspect you don't really need it unless you're hoping to trigger the `;` behavior of repeating `f`.

Comment: I tried removing it but at that i needed to press a button every time i used the shortcut.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble indeed I copied it for that reason. OP uses it as a hack for suppressing the output of the commands, which should probably be done with `:silent` and/or `<silent>` instead. I am going to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: And I can start the pattern search at a specific line number with +25/string/. I can also start at second instance of pattern with +/string//string/. And go three lines below that match with +/string//string/3. This is brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+cmd` is not limited to a single command. Several commands can be given, separated by "bars":

```
nnoremap mh :write\|edit +silent\ /pattern/\|normal\ zt filename<CR>
```

NOTES:

- `<Enter>` is replaced with `\|` so that you only have a single Ex command.
- `:w` and `:e` are replaced with the full command names, `:write` and `:edit`.
- `:help :normal` is an Ex command that allows you to execute normal mode commands from command-line mode. Here, it is used to do `zt`.
- The trailing `;`, that you use to remove the prompt caused by `:/pattern/` is removed in favor of a `:help :silent` before the search.

Comment: I don't understand edit and normal. But its working. Thanks.